# Why aren't my globals global?

Tags: python

I have the following lines at the beginning of my script:

```
global lotRow
global lotCol
```

Then, later on, I set lotRow and lotCol as strings using a function. Then, even later, I do the following:

```
getIDFromAxes(int(lotRow), int(lotCol))
```

This gives me:

```
    getIDFromAxes(str(lotRow), str(lotCol))
NameError: global name 'lotRow' is not defined
```

I have the def() print the "lot" strings at the end to be sure they are set, and I still can't access them for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`global` statements don't go at the beginning of a script; they go inside of a function that needs access to global variables. So rather than:

```
global x
x = 0

def increment_x():
    x += 1
    return x
```

You'll need to use:

```
x = 0

def increment_x():
    global x
    x += 1
    return x
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use the keyword `global` when inside the function that is trying to access your global variables, otherwise it will look for a local definition - which of course doesn't exist.

---

```
global global_variable
```

```
def set_var ():
  global global_variable

  global_variable = 3

def print_var ():
  global global_variable

  print int(global_variable)
```

```
set_var   ()
print_var ()

global_variable = 321

print_var ()
```

---

**output:**

```
3
321
```

Comment: but my `global` statements and `getIDFromAxes(int(lotRow), int(lotCol))` are both in the main script, and therefore the same function, correct?

Comment: If they're in the same function, why do you want them to be global at all? I think you'd better post some actual code.

Comment: @DanielRoseman got confused there for a second, forgot `getIDFromAxes()` was a function. Moving the global statements into the function seems to be working.